# Laravel 5.4 have Blank Page - No Error Display, No Error Log

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I Developed one Laravel Project. it has working in local environment properly. But, when i move the project to the server it has no error Shown. I check Error log, it has empty. i enabled `APP_DEBUG=true` to *.env* file and **config/app.php** also.

I give 777 permission for storage Folder. how to find error in my project, anybody help me...

Comment: This could be an apache issue. Can you please share the url that you are using?

Comment: it gives Internal Server Error. Please check the code if its working fine on the local system.

Comment: Its working fine Mr.@KinshukLahiri

Comment: It's `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`, check the Apache logs for the errors...

Comment: What environment are you using? What are you using to serve it?

Comment: I using Shared Hosting. Cpanel... @developernator

Comment: Apache Logs have no Errors. @AkshayKhale

Comment: Are your routes working? I've had issues on some shared hosting with routing...

Comment: make sure, composer packages are there in vendor directory with permission and check PHP FPM logs if possible... @Karthik

Answer (score 3):

Change `storage` and `logs` folder permission to : **0755**

and

`laravel.log` file permission to : **0644**

For any folder to be accessible by script, permission should be set to 0755 and for files to 0644 in standard production scenario.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me chmod -R 777 storage/

I'm using brew. Hope it could help.